# How to use Git worktree on host-guest file system in virtual machine

Tags: linux, windows, git, virtual-machine, git-worktree

I'm opening a new worktree in my local repository in Windows, and can't compile it in my Linux virtual machine, because the ".git" contains a full path starting with "C:/Git" that the virtual machine does not recognize.

I have a git repository that I often need to cross-compile on both Windows and Linux.
I originally cloned the repository in my windows system and mounted my "C:" drive as a shared file system in a virtual Ubuntu machine.
This usually works perfectly fine.

When attempting to open a new worktree in git, the linked repository doesn't have it's own ".git" folder, but rather a link to the original repository's ".git" folder, and this is saved as an absolute path, in the following format:

```
gitdir: C:/Git/...
```

When attempting to run:

```
git rev-parse
```

I get the following message:

```
fatal: not a git repository: /mnt/hgfs/WindowsDriveC/Git/WorktreeDir/C:/Git/OriginalGitDir/.git/worktrees/WorktreeDir
```

Due to this limitation, several of my scripts fail.

Is there any way to "trick" Linux into recognizing the full path and properly identifying the original git repo?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, doing this kind of thing is discouraged because it can lead to corruption, and as you've seen the Windows paths don't play well with the Linux paths.

However, that being said, there are a couple of options. One is to set up the worktree under Cygwin or Windows Subsystem for Linux and share it. That will still result in a path that doesn't exist on the Linux VM, but it would be possible to create a symlink from `/cygdrive/c` or `/mnt/c` to `/mnt/hgfs/WindowsDriveC` and then the rest of the stuff would work.

Another option is just to use Windows Subsystem for Linux, which means that you can do your compilation and produce Windows binaries without leaving Windows. You'd produce Linux binaries, but you wouldn't have to worry about sharing with the VM. The worktree would need to be created under WSL, though.

A final option is to edit the `.git` file in the worktree to use a relative path to the main repository. This is unsupported and might break, but then again it might work for your needs. Be sure to use forward slashes for that purpose.

Comment: What format would you use for the relative path? and what kind of corruption could this lead to?  I have a repo synced between two Windows computers but they each have different paths, so the absolute path breaks

Comment: You would use something like `../other/repo`.

Comment: I don't understand. If I make a worktree and change the .git file to a relative path it still works, but one that has been moved doesn't work, even if changed to an absolute path. Winmerge shows no other difference between the two worktrees. Just the branch name in the .git file.

Comment: Oh I think it needs to be changed in multiple places. The `.git\worktrees\BranchName\gitdir` file has an absolute path too

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem. What are all the files that you changed, apart from .git\worktrees\BranchName\gitdir to make it works? I can ask a new question if you want. thx.